# Should I remove "to" in this sentence

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, complements

> They went **to** jogging this morning.
>
> They went jogging this morning.

Should I remove "to" in this sentence,If yes than why.

Comment: Yes, remove it. You can say _they went jogging this morning_ or you can say _they went to jog this morning_, but you wouldn't say _they went to jogging this morning_.

Comment: What @J.R. said. The only valid verb I can think of offhand that works with **to [gerund]** is [(he) **set to** (complaining)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22set+to+complaining%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I can't think of any way the *-ing* verb form can be a *present participle* preceded by **to**. Unless you look on *jogging, boxing, weight-lifting, etc.* as nouns naming alternative activities you might go to on different days, perhaps.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions about the word "to". Is there something particular about it that confuses you, so we can help?

Comment: @FumbleFingers there's also: I look forward to seeing/meeting/hearing you. Maybe Amish Aa is confused when "to" is a preposition and the verb that follows is in the gerund, and when "to" is part of the infinite verb as in "to jog"?

Comment: But! If I were taking a class on jogging, then it would be possible to say, "I went to Jogging this morning."

Comment: @Jim: I don't know the terminology for the distinction, but the "archetypal" gerund seems to me to be as in *"I like jogging"*. Which can accommodate an adverb, as in *"I like jogging **slowly**"*. But I don't think you could ever say *"I went to **Jogging slowly** this morning."* So it must somehow be a different kind of gerund - or maybe it's not a gerund after all, I don't know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- In this case it would be the name of a continuing education class- Jogging, Welding, Public Speaking, Swimming...  And, if I were sad about last night's events, I might say, "I went to Jogging slowly this morning, knowing she wouldn't be there anymore."

Answer (score 7):

I think I understand where your confusion stems from, but please correct me if I am wrong!

You are confusing verbs that take the [**gerund**](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-ing-clauses) or the [**infinitive**](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive).
Some verbs *usually* take the gerund for example; **enjoy, hate, finish, mind, practise, spend, suggest, stop** and phrasal verbs, e.g. **give up, go on, take up** etc.

> 1. He enjoyed swimming a lot.
> 2. They hate writing stories for homework.
> 3. May I suggest visiting the local museum?
> 4. She can't give up smoking.

Then there are verbs which *normally* take the infinitive. These include; **agree, decide, help, learn, promise, want, would like** etc.

> 1. He decided to swim in the lake.
> 2. They didn't want to write a story for homework.
> 3. Would you like to visit the local museum?
> 4. She promised to look after herself more.

However, there are verbs which take both the gerund and the infinite for example: remember, start, try, forget etc.

The verb: **GO** often takes the **gerund** especially when we talk about hobbies and [**sports**](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/go_gerund.htm).

> 1. I go fishing every Sunday.
> 2. He goes jogging in the park.
> 3. We went skiing in France.

But **go** is also used in conjunction with [**to**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to), the preposition, when we are talking about getting or arriving at places, and **to**, the [**particle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle), when we make verbs in the infinitive i.e. **to + verb** (see brackets) to indicate purpose.

> 1. I go to the lake (to fish) = A:"Why do you go to the lake?" B:"To fish."
> 2. He goes to the park (to jog). = A: "Why does he go to the park?" B: "To jog." etc.
> 3. We went to France (to ski).
> 4. She didn't want to **go to bed** (to sleep).

So, you can say: **"They went jogging"** because, jogging is a sport activity which we use with the verb, go. But it is also possible to say: **They went to the park to jog** or even **They went to jog** (in the park). You can also leave out "in the park" and still have a grammatical sentence.

P.S I tried looking high and low for references with examples of uses for **go + infinitive**, and **go + gerund** and failed miserably!

Comment: All looks good to me. There's some interesting stuff [here on the British Council's "Learn English" site](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/infinitive), where they cover **verb + infinitive/gerund** (but no **go**! :)

Comment: Also (I **hate to mention** this), *love/hate* are often used with the infinitive (as the nitpicker in me **loves to point out**). The others look right though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are absolutely right but that's why I did say: "usually" followed by "normally" and then mentioned that some verbs take both forms! :) But I was also surprised to see how "go to + verb" examples seemed to be avoided in those very websites which are aimed at ELL (or) ESOL. And many thanks to Wendikidd for making my answer look more presentable, she probably saved me 20 minutes work!

Comment: Here's [Mark Twain's *Huckleberry Finn*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22When+I+got+by+myself+I+went+to+thinking+the+thing+over%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) saying *"When I got by myself I **went to thinking** the thing over".* It sounds a bit antiquated/dialectal to me, but the form is [obviously still in use](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+to+thinking&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: That it may still be in use is one thing, that it is correct is another! That we hear it in everyday speech yet another. I have never heard anyone saying: *I went to thinking* not even non-native speakers! Finn's quote illustrates that he wasn't schooled, but in its context it is perfectly comprehensible. I think this is a case of artistic license. :)

Comment: The fact that Huck is unschooled isn't really relevant. There's obviously no "grammatical rule" saying you can't use *went* in this way, so you're effectively suggesting the usage be classified as "incorrect" simply because it's *uncommon/dated/regional/dialectal/whatever*. [This writer](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22always+went+to+thinking%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, clearly has an impressive command of English. I also see my hero Arlo's father [Woody Guthrie used it](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fog+so+I+went+to+thinking%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Well, can we agree that it is less common than "[I began thinking](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fog+so+I+went+to+thinking%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I+began+thinking%22&oq=%22I+began+thinking%22&gs_l=serp.12...14284.18281.2.19951.12.12.0.0.0.0.168.1605.0j12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab._sY5QXlus_Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZWU&fp=13be8b46e4ab0848&biw=1348&bih=596) 329,000 results" or "I started thinking" 765,000 results"? And if this is the case, why is it so? (2nd link was too long to post)

Comment: @Fumble: I gots to thinkin' about this, and I'm thinkin' Huck's non-schooling *is* relevant; fact be, Twain seems to be emphasizing it. 'Sample bein' the passage you quote, which goes on to say: "I knowed very well where the right plan was going to come from." "Knowed"? Ain't too many incidents of the expression found, and much o' those quotes seem to be replete with rather informal language: "I walked a few steps and seen it was too rainy and bad to see in the fog, so I went to thinking about some kind of a place to lay down." In my little bit o' research, I seen lots o' quotes like that one.

Comment: @J.R., Mari-Lou: I don't want to overstate my case there. I absolutely agree *went to thinking* is "non-standard". I'm just saying that I don't see it as "incorrect" according to any meaningful rule of grammar. If a native speaker can (or maybe, *could*) use a form "naturally", I'm not inclined to label it "incorrect" unless it clearly violates established grammar - as in *"I would **of** done something"*, which I have no hesitation in classifying as ***wrong***, no matter how many native speakers say it.